# Bundle Product not visible at frontend after upgrading to 1.7.0.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

Bundle product is not visible at the front end maybe due to js issue, after upgrading from 1.6 to 1.7.0.1

debugging with firebug i found the following js error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::getBasePrice() in /var/www/vhosts/stage.planetjill.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Price.php on line 117
</script>
```

the method in price.php

```
 public function getFinalPrice($qty = null, $product)
    {
        if (is_null($qty) && !is_null($product->getCalculatedFinalPrice())) {
            return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
        }
        $finalPrice = $this->getBasePrice($product, $qty);
        //$finalPrice = $product->getPrice();
        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty));
        $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');

        $finalPrice = $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice);
        $finalPrice += $this->getTotalBundleItemsPrice($product, $qty);

        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
        return max(0, $product->getData('final_price'));
    }
```

if you see the commented line

> //**$finalPrice = $product->getPrice();**

which was used in magento 1.6. If i use this line in place of

> **$finalPrice = $this->getBasePrice($product, $qty);**

the bundle product is now visible but the price as configured is always set to 0 and addtocart button breaks.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check is there any js error might be in product.js file

Answer (score 1):

I would check your template files, probably /app/design/xxx/xxx/bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml -- Make sure the call to $_product->getFinalPrice() is hooked up properly (ie. if you get_class_methods($this) it is the proper class that has getFinalPrice() accessible)

If it isn't you should grep through any modules that are installed and check to see if Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price is being rewritten.

Alternatively, go through and disable modules via the module's .xml file one by one until the problem is fixed. Isolate from there.